# Tensorflow-Python - Is it possible to freeze a graph using tf.Estimator without including the "RandomShuffleQueueV2" and the "QueueDequeueMany" nodes?

Tags: android, python, tensorflow

This is still about that graph problem. I've managed to remove the nodes from `RandomShuffleQueueV2` up to `QueueDequeueMany` in my graph, so now it looks like this:

```
['Reshape/shape => Placeholder',
 'Reshape => Reshape',
 'conv2d/kernel => Const',
 'conv2d/bias => Const',
 'conv2d/convolution => Conv2D',
 'conv2d/BiasAdd => BiasAdd',
 'conv2d/Relu => Relu',
 'conv2d_1/kernel => Const',
 'conv2d_1/bias => Const',
 'conv2d_2/convolution => Conv2D',
 'conv2d_2/BiasAdd => BiasAdd',
 'conv2d_2/Relu => Relu',
 'max_pooling2d/MaxPool => MaxPool',
 'conv2d_2/kernel => Const',
 'conv2d_2/bias => Const',
 'conv2d_3/convolution => Conv2D',
 'conv2d_3/BiasAdd => BiasAdd',
 'conv2d_3/Relu => Relu',
 'conv2d_3/kernel => Const',
 'conv2d_3/bias => Const',
 'conv2d_4/convolution => Conv2D',
 'conv2d_4/BiasAdd => BiasAdd',
 'conv2d_4/Relu => Relu',
 'max_pooling2d_2/MaxPool => MaxPool',
 'conv2d_4/kernel => Const',
 'conv2d_4/bias => Const',
 'conv2d_5/convolution => Conv2D',
 'conv2d_5/BiasAdd => BiasAdd',
 'conv2d_5/Relu => Relu',
 'conv2d_5/kernel => Const',
 'conv2d_5/bias => Const',
 'conv2d_6/convolution => Conv2D',
 'conv2d_6/BiasAdd => BiasAdd',
 'conv2d_6/Relu => Relu',
 'max_pooling2d_3/MaxPool => MaxPool',
 'Reshape_1/shape => Const',
 'Reshape_1 => Reshape',
 'dense/kernel => Const',
 'dense/bias => Const',
 'dense/MatMul => MatMul',
 'dense/BiasAdd => BiasAdd',
 'dense/Relu => Relu',
 'dropout/dropout/keep_prob => Const',
 'dropout/dropout/Shape => Const',
 'dropout/dropout/random_uniform/min => Const',
 'dropout/dropout/random_uniform/max => Const',
 'dropout/dropout/random_uniform/RandomUniform => RandomUniform',
 'dropout/dropout/random_uniform/sub => Sub',
 'dropout/dropout/random_uniform/mul => Mul',
 'dropout/dropout/random_uniform => Add',
 'dropout/dropout/add => Add',
 'dropout/dropout/Floor => Floor',
 'dropout/dropout/div => RealDiv',
 'dropout/dropout/mul => Mul',
 'dense_1/kernel => Const',
 'dense_1/bias => Const',
 'dense_2/MatMul => MatMul',
 'dense_2/BiasAdd => BiasAdd',
 'softmax_tensor => Softmax']
```

The thing is, when I try to use this graph in Tensorflow-Android, apparently it's not a valid Tensorflow graph:

```
Tensorflow-Android exception:
java.io.IOException: Not a valid TensorFlow Graph serialization: Node 'Reshape': Unknown input node 'random_shuffle_queue_DequeueMany:2'

OpenCV-DNN exception:
CvException [org.opencv.core.CvException: cv::Exception: F:\opencv-master\modules\dnn\src\tensorflow\tf_importer.cpp:552: error: (-2) Const kernel input not found in function const tensorflow::TensorProto& cv::dnn::experimental_dnn_v1::{anonymous}::TFImporter::getConstBlob(const tensorflow::NodeDef&, std::map<cv::String, int>, int, int*)
```

`random_shuffle_queue_DequeueMany:2` is among the nodes I deleted.

How can I make sure `Reshape/shape` is an independent Input Node so I can port it to Android? Or should I just train WITHOUT using `tf.Estimator()`?

Answer (score 0):

You don't mention how you are removing the nodes, but if you use the Graph Transform Tool `strip_unused_nodes` rule, it should fix the input naming error you're seeing:
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/tools/graph_transforms/#strip_unused_nodes

Comment: Actually I used the modified version of the `remove_training_nodes()` function copied from tensorflow's `graph_util_impl.py`.